# Selecting time ranges for creating an event not working in day and week view with jquery 1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Earlier i was using jquery 1.7.0 and every thing was working fine.
But when i upgraded to **jquery 1.8** ***Selecting time ranges for creating an event is not working*** in agendaWeek and agendaDay but works fine with month.

Here is my code :

```
$('#Calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    firstHour: (new Date()).getHours(),
    minTime: 4,
    maxTime: 24,
    slotMinutes: 15,
    allDaySlot: false,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    eventSources: [
    // code for event source

    ],
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    ignoreTimezone: true,
    loading: function (isLoading) {
        //code for image loading
           .............
    },
    select:function (start, end, allDay) {
           //Code on Select   
           ................     
                },
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        //Code on event clicked
             .......................
        });
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
       // Code on event Rendered
            .................
        });
    }
});
```

When i am using jquery 1.7 Selecting time ranges for creating an event in day and week works perfectly as shown in fig below.
[image]

However **Selecting time ranges for creating an event stops working** when i upgrade to jquery1.8.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which version of FullCalendar are you using? In FullCalendar's changelog I can see that some jQuery 1.8 compatibility issues were fixed in version 1.5.4. Check out the changelog here: https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/changelog.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is given by Regin Larsen in the comments.
Need to upgrade fullcalendar to version **1.5.4** and jquery ui to **1.8.23.**